# Array index out of range Query and CollectionCell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

for some reason I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

I am trying to Query for URLS in my Parse Database, put these into an array called `facebookPics`. Later I want in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check,

```
if facebookPics.count < indexPath.row
```

Then load Data in my CollectionViewCells. => I have exactly 6 each time.

Code:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let infoQuery = PFUser.query()
    infoQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectID!)

    infoQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{

            let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
        else if results != nil{

            for result in results! {


                let imageFile = result["firstImage"] as! PFFile
                // Image muss ja erstmal gedownloaded werden.
                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        return

                    } else {
                        if let data = imageData {

                            self.miniImage.image = UIImage(data: data)

                        }

                    }

                }
                // Jetzt der firstname, birthday und abouttext
                var profilText = result["first_name"] as! String
                self.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText

                if let geburtstag = result["birthday"] as? String {

                    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                    let currentDate = NSDate()
                    let birthdayFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    birthdayFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
                    let birthday = birthdayFormatter.dateFromString(geburtstag)



                    let ageComponents = calendar.components(.Year,
                        fromDate: birthday!,
                        toDate: currentDate,
                        options: [])


                    let age = ageComponents.year


                    profilText += ", " + String(age)
                    self.nameAgeLabel.text = profilText


                }


                if let hashtags = result["hashtags"] as? String {

                    self.hashtagText.text = hashtags

                }

                if let images = result["images"] as? [String] {



                    for image in images {

                        let nsURL = NSURL(string: image)
                        var urls:[NSURL] = [NSURL]()
                        urls.append(nsURL!)
                        self.facebookPics = urls

                    }

                    print(self.facebookPics)


                }






            }

            self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()


        }
    })

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "Überschrift.png")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    // Navigation Controller Top soll Durchsichtig sein
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.opaque = true

    miniImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    miniImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    miniImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    miniImage.layer.cornerRadius = miniImage.frame.width/2
    miniImage.clipsToBounds = true

    hashtagText.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    hashtagText.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkTextColor().CGColor
    hashtagText.layer.cornerRadius = 7







    // Suche starten um folgende Infos zu bekommen [Profilbild, firstname, abouttext, andere Bilder adressen.]





}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

// Alle images.count => returnen! max 6



return 6



}
//FEHLERHAFTE FUNKTION



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let collectionCell:SettingsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsCollectionViewCell

    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    collectionCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionCell.frame.size.width = 80
    collectionCell.frame.size.height = 80
    collectionCell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    collectionCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
    collectionCell.layer.cornerRadius = collectionCell.frame.size.width/2




    if facebookPics.count < indexPath.row{

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookPics[indexPath.row]) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = image
        }
    }

    else {
        // Clear out the image on a recycled cell
        collectionCell.collectionViewImage = nil
    }


    let cellImage = collectionCell.collectionViewImage

    if cellImage == nil {

        self.counter = 1
        print("empty")
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.center.x = 40
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.center.y = 40
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)



    }
    else {

        self.counter = 0
        print("hello")
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.center.x = 60
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.center.y = 60
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "close-o.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        collectionCell.collectionViewButton.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }







    return collectionCell
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? crash? not working as expected?

Comment: As said in the description _>         if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookPics[indexPath.row]) {
 throws the array out of index error

Comment: That was not mentioned in the description so far. And please remove the 9000 blank lines in the source code, gets very hard to navigate with them.

Comment: Nevermind, found the issue anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **invert the if condition**.

Your current code goes into the if block if you have 0 images and try to show the 3rd one since 0 < 3 evaluates to true. That is exactly the opposite of what you want. More general you currently only enter the true-branch if and only if the index is exactly out of bounds.

The correct check is:

```
if indexPath.row < facebookPics.count {
    // logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now xCode throws an error saying                 collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = image    /// Found Nil unwrapping an Optional

Comment: I think, now that my facebookpics array is greater than the max cells of 6 I am getting an error since XCODE tries to catch cell number 7. I actually don't know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but this finally works.

```
    if indexPath.row < facebookPics.count {
        if let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: self.facebookPics[indexPath.row]){

            let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
            collectionCell.collectionViewImage.image = image

        }
    }
```